# OSMesa GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT error when create a multisampling FBO

Tags: rendering, mesa

I have tried to do offscreen rendering in my linux server(a virtual machine with no graphics card and no window system) by OSMesa, refer to the osmesa demo [osdemos](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2827). Every thing works fine.

For antialiasing, i tried to create a multisamping render buffer to bind to FBO, but result with GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT, the single sampled render buffer works fine.
here is the code to create the FBO, change the sample_number for 1, works fine, for 4 with GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT error. Any suggestions are appricate.

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "GL/osmesa.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int Width = 1920;
const int Height = 1080;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   OSMesaContext ctx;
   void *buffer;

#if OSMESA_MAJOR_VERSION * 100 + OSMESA_MINOR_VERSION >= 305
   ctx = OSMesaCreateContextExt( OSMESA_RGBA, 32, 0, 0, NULL );
#else
   ctx = OSMesaCreateContext( OSMESA_RGBA, NULL );
#endif
   if (!ctx) {
      printf("OSMesaCreateContext failed!\n");
      return 0;
   }

   buffer = malloc( Width * Height * 4 * sizeof(GLubyte) );
   if (!buffer) {
      printf("Alloc image buffer failed!\n");
      return 0;
   }

   if (!OSMesaMakeCurrent( ctx, buffer, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Width, Height )) {
      printf("OSMesaMakeCurrent failed!\n");
      return 0;
   }

   int render_width = 200, render_height = 200;

    enum { Color, Depth, NumRenderbuffers };
    // multi-sampled frame buffer object as the draw target
    GLuint framebuffer_ms, renderbuffer_ms[NumRenderbuffers];

    // generate color and depth render buffers and allocate storage for the multi-sampled FBO
    glGenRenderbuffers(NumRenderbuffers, renderbuffer_ms);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer_ms[Color]);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, // here set 1 works fine
        GL_RGBA8, render_width, render_height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer_ms[Depth]);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, // here set 1 works fine
        GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, render_width, render_height);

    // generate frame buffer object for the multi-sampled FBO
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_ms);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_ms);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
        GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer_ms[Color]);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, 
        GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer_ms[Depth]);
    auto status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
   if (status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      std::cout << "fbo status fine!!!" << std::endl;
   } else {
      std::cout << "Failed:" << status << std::endl;
   }
   exit(__LINE__);

    // render_image();
    // std::vector<GLubyte> data(width *height * 4);
    // glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    // glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
    // write_targa(data.data(), width, height);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_ms);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(2, renderbuffer_ms);

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the post processing to do anti-aliasing. pp_jimenezmlaa and pp_jimenezmlaaa_color

Comment: pp_jimenezmlaa's result not very good,  As my scene have no background, and I save the result to png file, when with a black background the result looks fine, but when with white background the jagged edges is obvious as original one.